# 誤ってgit daemonしたときの対処法

Tags: git, tortoisegit

Windows10・TortoiseGitで、GitとGitHubを使っています。

今回誤ってTortoiseGitで「バックグラウンド稼働」をクリックしてしまいました。
外部に公開する気が全くなかったので、直後に出てくる外部に公開されますがよろしいですか？のようなダイアログで「中止」をクリックして事なきを得ましたが、将来誤って実際にバックグラウンド稼働（`git daemon`）してしまったときに備えて、以下の質問をします。

1. 実際にバックグラウンド稼働してしまったときには、どうすればバックグラウンド稼働を止められますか？
2. バックグラウンド稼働しているか否かを確認する方法はありますか？

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TortoiseGit からの操作で、「バックグラウンド稼働」で確認ダイアログにも「続行」を選んだ場合、以下のようなダイアログが表示されますが、**このダイアログが表示されている間だけ** バックグラウンド稼働の機能が有効なようです。「中止」を押せば機能は停止します。
(試した限りだと "閉じる" ボタンは有効になりませんでした)

なお、既にご存知かと思いますが「バックグラウンド稼働」は `git-daemon` を GUI から呼び出しているだけなので、TortoiseGit での操作であれば前述の通り「ダイアログが表示されている間」が稼働中です。
Windows のタスクマネージャー等でプロセスを確認すれば "git-daemon.exe" が動いているはずです。

**"バックグラウンド稼働" を実行中の画面:**

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

蛇足ですが、普段めったに使わないコンテキストメニューは設定から非表示にしておくと誤操作を防げます。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

**確認環境:**
TortoiseGit 2.10.0.2
Git for Windows 2.28.0